# Jquery FullCalendar doesnt gets displayed completely

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, fullcalendar

I am using Jquery FullCalendar in my website. It works fine on chrome, Mozilla and Internet Explorer, but fails to dislay complete calendar on Safari browser.
Here is the view on SAFARi
[image: Untitled.png]

I checked the FullCalendar support it works fine on Safari, but still i am getting this issue.
If anybody knows why this is happening please help.
My safari version is 5.1.7
Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you checked the developer console in Safari for any errors/warnings? According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history your version has not been in mainstream support for 4 years now, so there's a good chance the web has moved on and there's something within either fullCalendar or one of its depedencies that isn't supported by this quite old version of the browser. Have you tested on a supported version of Safari?

Comment: P.S. If you are using Safari for Windows, that's discontinued after your version, so really you don't need to worry about it, there's unlikely to be anyone using it. Safari for Mac is a different matter, of course.

Comment: I guessed so @ADyson . Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @ADyson Do you know any website where I can test my website in local host for New versions of safari? That will be very helpfull

Comment: if it's in localhost then you need to have the relevant browser on your own machine, because your localhost is not usually accessible from the internet. If you upload the site to some free hosting account you can use sites like BrowserStack to test - you can get a time-limited free account. There may be others, but that's one that I know of. There are some free/shareware emulators out there as well for iOS/Android if that's relevant to you.